# How to get the union, intersection and difference of two given Hashtables?

Tags: linq, hashtable, union, intersection, difference

I have two Hashtables.

I'm trying to get the union, intersection and difference but how can I loop and compare between these two hashtables *(`hashtable1.Count` is not equal `hashtable2.Count`)*, does anyone know how to do it with **linq** ?

```
public Hashtable operator +(Hashtable g1, Hashtable g2) //union
    {
        Hashtable result = new Hashtable();
        //loop
        {
            if(!result.Contains(g1[i]))
            {
                result.Add(g1[i]);
            }
            if(!result.Contains(g2[i]))
            {
                result.Add(g2[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public Hashtable operator -(Hashtable g1, Hashtable g2) //intersection 
    {
        Hashtable result = new Hashtable();
        //loop
        {
            if (g1[i] == g2[i])
            {
                result.Add(g1[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public Hashtable operator /(Hashtable g1, Hashtable g2) //difference 
    {
        Hashtable result = new Hashtable();
        //loop
        {
            if (g1[i] != g2[i])
            {
                result.Add(g1[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Any good reason to use an Hashtable instead of a generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` ? This would make all the linq stuff much easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's gonna be rather hard to use `IEnumerable<T>` extensions methods  if you use an Hashtable instead of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Because an Hashtable is not a generic type.

So there's no `Hashtable.Union` available, nore `Hashtable.Keys.Union`.

You would have to do something like

```
hashtable1.Keys.Cast<int>().Union(hashtable2.Keys.Cast<int>());
```

But... what will happen if keys are not int ?

If you change `Hashtable` to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you'll be able to do things like

```
var resultDictionary = dic1.Intersects(dic2).ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);

var resultDictionary = dic1.Except(dic2).ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);
```